# How to sum all value based on multiple data input in one cell

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, gs-vlookup

I have a sheet like this

```
A       B     C                            D
Apple   10    Apple Apple Orange Melon     
Orange  30 
Melon   50
```

I want D1 to show the sum value based on the value in C1 which is 2 apples, oranges, and Melon (10+10+30+50) = 100

Any advice on what to type in column D1? I assume it will be related to `sumif`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the previous formula, this should probably also work:

```
=sum(ArrayFormula(iferror(vlookup(split(C1, " "), A1:B, 2, 0))))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUMPRODUCT(QUERY({A1:B, IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1:A, 
 QUERY(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(C1, " ")), 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) group by Col1", 0), 2, 0))}, 
 "select Col2*Col3")))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: thank you very much, i tried ur formula but its a bit too complicated for me when i tried to implement it in the real sheet :( 
and then i got answer from others
thank you for caring